# Is converting a mixed-fraction to an improper fraction is just adding the remaining part to the whole?

Tags: education, fractions

For example, if you're simplifying $3 \frac{1}{2}$, the conventional way is to do $3 \cdot 2$ and then add the numerator $1$.
Isn't this the same as adding $3/1$ and $1/2$?

Comment: It is since $\frac{3}{1}=\frac{6}{2}$ and now adding $\frac{1}{2}$ is no problem any more.

Comment: Yes, since *by definition* $\,3\frac{1}2 = \frac{3}1+\frac{1}2.\,$ More generally if one denominator is a common multiple of all the others, say $\,b = b_k b_k',\,$ then we have a similar simplification of fraction addition  
$$\dfrac{a}b + \dfrac{a_1}{b_1} +\cdots + \dfrac{a_n}{b_n} = \dfrac{a+ a_1 b_1'+\cdots + a_n b_n'}{b}\qquad\qquad $$

Answer (score 5):

Yes. The reason you multiply the 3 by the 2 is that you are really forming the numerator of a fraction with a common denominator, since $3\frac12$ really means $3 + \frac12$. So:
$$3 + \frac12 = \frac31 + \frac12$$
$$= \frac{3\cdot 2}{1\cdot2} + \frac12$$
$$=\frac{3\cdot 2}2 + \frac12$$
$$=\frac{3\cdot2 + 1}2$$
$$=\frac72$$
The "shortcut" skips from line 1 to line 4: $$3 +\dfrac12 =\frac{3\cdot2 + 1}2 =\frac72$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, obviously: the meaning of $3 \frac{1}{2}$ is $3 + \frac{1}{2}$, which comes down to $\frac{2 \cdot 3}{2} + \frac{1}{2}$, which is equal to $\frac{2 \cdot 3 + 1}{2}$, which is equal to $\frac{7}{2}$.